# Input string of text and have multiple value with one argument

Tags: c

So I want to input my string of text and have multiple value with one argument.

For example: if I input Kamis, I want the output to be Jumat. But I got Selasa. And every time I type other input it always end up with Selasa output.

How to solve this?

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

char nama_hari_besok(char* Nama_Hari_Ini);

void main(){
    char Nama_Hari_Ini, hari_ini;

    printf("FUNGSI NEXTDAY\n\n");
    printf("Masukkan nama hari ini= ");
    scanf(" %c", &Nama_Hari_Ini);
    Nama_Hari_Ini=nama_hari_besok(&Nama_Hari_Ini);
}

char nama_hari_besok(char* Nama_Hari_Ini){
    if(Nama_Hari_Ini, "Senin"){
        printf("Besok adalah hari Selasa\n");
    }
    else if (Nama_Hari_Ini, "Selasa"){
        printf("Besok adalah hari Rabu\n");
    }
    else if (Nama_Hari_Ini ="Rabu"){
        printf("Besok adalah hari Kamis\n");
    }
    else if (Nama_Hari_Ini ="Kamis"){
        printf("Besok adalah hari Jumat\n");
    }
    else if (Nama_Hari_Ini ="Jumat"){
        printf("Besok adalah hari Sabtu\n");
    }
    else if (Nama_Hari_Ini ="Sabtu"){
        printf("Besok adalah hari Minggu\n");
    }
    else if (Nama_Hari_Ini ="Minggu"){
        printf("Besok adalah hari Senin\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Error\n");
    }
return Nama_Hari_Ini;
}```
````

Comment: This isn't how strings work in C. If you are coming from a higher level language, please note that C doesn't have a string class. It's kind of pointless to post an answer - you must simply study arrays, pointers and strings in C, preferably in that order.

Comment: What do you think `if (Nama_Hari_Ini, "Senin")` does?

Comment: And well, voting to close as too board - there's too much wrong with this code. Pointing out all problems requires typing out the whole string chapter of a beginner level book. Basically you can't do programming with trial & error.

Comment: Aida Arisa, Tip:  Enable all compiler warnings to recieve fast feedback as to many code problems.

Comment: Sounds like you need an associative array. If your values are constant, [gperf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/) is amazing, otherwise, [GLib HashTable](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.HashTable.html) seems popular.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not comparing strings correctly.

You can not use `=` in C to compare strings, you must use `strcmp`:

```
if(strcmp(Nama_Hari_Ini, "Senin") == 0){
    printf("Besok adalah hari Selasa\n");
}
else if (strcmp(Nama_Hari_Ini, "Selasa") == 0){
    printf("Besok adalah hari Rabu\n");
}
```

Comment: And not assigning them correctly. And not allocating them correctly. And not reading them correctly. And so on.